# Save XLSM to XLSX

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to convert my XLSM to XLSX File..it was before transformation to PDF, and I tried to change a bit but didnt succeed.

I wanna to have the same name as the workbook has, but just in XLSX format.

```
Sub xlsmtoxlsx()
Dim PathFile As String
Dim PathArray() As String
Dim PathPDF As String
   
'Get file path
PathFile = Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName

'Split file path in path and file ending
PathArray() = Split(PathFile, ".")

'Creat file path with ".pdf" ending
PathPDF = PathArray(0) & ".xlsx"
    
'PDF File is saved in directory of workbook
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypeXlsx, Filename:= _
    PathPDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
'Closes Workbook after generating PDF
ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
Application.Quit
```

Comment: Use `SaveAs` instead of `ExportAsFixedFormat`.

Comment: `ExportAsFixedFormat` is only for PDF/XPS [xlFixedFormatType enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfixedformattype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Backup as `XLSX`

```
Option Explicit

Sub BackupAsXLSX()
    
    ' Create a reference to the source workbook.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Determine the destination file path ('FullName').
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = swb.FullName
    Dim DotPosition As Long: DotPosition = InStrRev(sFilePath, ".")
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = Left(sFilePath, DotPosition) & "xlsx"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy all sheets to a new (destination) workbook.
    swb.Sheets.Copy
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' Save and close the destination workbook.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "XLSX backup created.", vbInformation
    
    ' Note that the source workbook hasn't been modified in any way.
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.